# rabbitmq openshift cluster

Tags: rabbitmq, openshift

I setup rabbitmq cluster on my openshift successfully.

However I don't find the way to expose amqp (5672) or amqps (5671) ports with openshift routes.

I saw on openshift documentation that is not supported.
https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/architecture/core_concepts/routes.html

***Routers support the following protocols:
HTTP
HTTPS (with SNI)
WebSockets
TLS with SNI
WebSocket traffic uses the same route conventions and supports the same TLS termination types as other traffic.***

what is the best way for doing this?

please find my setup.

oc version
oc v1.4.1
kubernetes v1.4.0+776c994
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO
openshift v1.4.1
kubernetes v1.4.0+776c994

POD router used : openshift/origin-haproxy-router:v1.4.1

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options. See:

- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/dev_guide/getting_traffic_into_cluster.html#using-externalIP
- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/dev_guide/getting_traffic_into_cluster.html#using-nodeport
- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/admin_guide/tcp_ingress_external_ports.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try your solutions and  I found other way to do that with the router : https://blog.zhaw.ch/icclab/openshift-custom-router-with-tcpsni-support/ so I will try also.